# Default constraint for datetime column is not getting the correct time

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, ssis

I'm troubleshooting an issue with a table constraint. The constraint is built to update a column in the table with the current date when the row is inserted. An SSIS package inserts data into the table.

If I run the insert manually from a query, it works correctly. If I run the SSIS package manually then it inserts the correct date but the time is always 07:00 or 08:00.

Here's the constraint:

```
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[table_name] ADD  CONSTRAINT [constraint_name]  DEFAULT (getdate()) FOR [column_name]
```

Adding to my original post, here is a sample of what the date's look like. You can see that it's not exactly 07:00 or 08:00 but within milliseconds to seconds.

[image: Constraint Dates]

Comment: "time is always 07:00 or 08:00" what's your timezone?

Comment: @JacobH Eastern Standard

Comment: Logic would dictate that something in your package is overriding the default (e.g. you're manually inserting into the column rather than letting it be the default value).

Comment: @ZLK I'll admit that I didn't write the SSIS myself. However, it's not very complex and I've seen no reference to any task that could be overwriting the date. The inserts into the table are only to 3 columns. The 4th column being the date column.

Comment: Works just fine for me.  You have something going on you are not seeing.

Comment: Since you're saying it works fine with a regular insert but not when inserted via the package, I don't think it's a trigger or anything like that. So outside of looking at each step of your package (e.g. perhaps an update at the end if it's not part of the insert?), I'm not sure where else to look.

Comment: @ZLK Thanks for the input. I will take another look tomorrow and see what I am missing. I'm glad to know that I'm not crazy and the constraint should be working the same in SSIS. I will post an answer if I figure it out.

Comment: You are doing bulk load and row per batch or max commit size is too big ... just  make it 1 you will see different time but performance will go down and second and i doubt you have select smalldatetime for the column.

Comment: @sandeeprawat I think I see where you going with that idea. However, the process is only writing out 1 row at a time. It is a dynamic server connection in a foreach loop. If the server fails to connect for that loop iteration than it writes the server name out to this table and than runs the next iteration with a new server name. Other servers work but there's 1 or 2 that are failing.